# Flutter Build Failure: Unable to Find 'com.android.application' Plugin

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies, gradle-plugin

Iam just starting to learn flutter by following some resources online, I have yet to even create a project but Iam already faced with problem.

I am facing a build failure issue while trying to run my Flutter app on an Android device using Visual Studio Code. The error is pointing to a plugin identification issue regarding 'com.android.application'. Here's a snippet of the error message:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\newapp\newtest\android\app\build.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.android.application'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s

code in android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
 
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
 
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
 
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
 
tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

code in android/app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}
 
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}
 
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}
 
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
 
android {
    namespace "com.example.newtest"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
 
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
 
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
 
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
 
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.newtest"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
 
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
 
flutter {
    source '../..'
}
 
dependencies {}
```

I have attempted to create a new project to see if the issue persists, and unfortunately, it does. I have also ensured that the Android SDK is properly installed and the ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set. I've cleaned the project and got dependencies again using flutter clean and flutter pub get respectively, but the error still remains.

I tried to update dependencies but I couldn't update them, the debug console kept telling me to revert to the changes I made, so I gave up, or dont know how to update the dependencies, if you know how to update them, let me know that too.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!